# asp.net MVC 4 model [Key] attribute not recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

//my model
public class Roll
{
    [Key]
    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public long RandomSeed { get; set; }
    public string Expression { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public long Total { get; set; }
}

//my context
public class DiceboxContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Roll> Rolls { get; set; }
}

//my controller 

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace dicebox.Controllers
{
    public class RollController : Controller
    {
        private DiceboxContext db = new DiceboxContext();

        //
        // GET: /Roll/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Rolls.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Roll/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            Roll roll = db.Rolls.Find(id);
            if (roll == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(roll);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Roll/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Roll/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Roll roll)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Rolls.Add(roll);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(roll);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Roll/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            Roll roll = db.Rolls.Find(id);
            if (roll == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(roll);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Roll/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Roll roll)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(roll).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(roll);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Roll/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            Roll roll = db.Rolls.Find(id);
            if (roll == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(roll);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Roll/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Roll roll = db.Rolls.Find(id);
            db.Rolls.Remove(roll);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Most of this is boilerplate automatically generated code. Any time I hit the Any action except for the get /Roll/Create Action, it blows up with the following error message:

> System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Roll' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'Rolls' is based on type 'Roll' that has no keys defined.

But as you can already see, there is a key defined. There is also a key defined for the database table "Rolls" that backs this model. Every answer I get from google suggests adding the [Key] annotation, and I already have.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try renaming `Roll.Id` to `Roll.RollId` (it's EF's convention for how keys get named) and possibly making it an `int` instead of an unsigned int?  You shouldn't need annotation for a bog-standard entity definition.

Comment: You appear to be about half right, as the error is different if I use an int vs uint. This is the same TERRIBLE design flaw that turned me off of ruby on rails when it was new. The type and name of my key should not matter at all. Now I am getting "Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Roll'. Using the same DbCompiledModel to create contexts against different types of database servers is not supported. Instead, create a seperate DbCompiledModel for each type of server being used."

Comment: https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2085127-support-unsigned-integer-e-g-uint-properties-an - `uint`s aren't supported at all.  You could fake it by adding a positive/negative bitflag if you need to support negative values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the Id to an int:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

I copied your code into a new MVC project, scaffolded the Index, Create and Edit views and I was able to both create and edit Rolls with no issue.